# Burninate [writing] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [writing](/questions/tagged/writing) tag doesn't seem to serve any real purpose. Almost all questions tagged with it would be just as good without it. It doesn't seem to have a very high number of questions on it either.

Could it be removed, or merged with another, more specific write operation tag?

Comment: I don't think it's _totally_ useless as such. It should certainly be replaced with something more descriptive, though.